# Find all nodes by attribute in XML using Python 2

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing

I have an XML file which has a lot of different nodes with the same attribute.

I was wondering if it's possible to find all these nodes using Python and any additional package like minidom or ElementTree.

Comment: thanks guys, i was using minidom and seems like it's not so powerful, will move to ElementTree finally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use built-in [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module.

If you want all elements that have a particular attribute regardless of the attribute values, you can use an *xpath expression*:

```
//tag[@attr]
```

Or, if you care about values:

```
//tag[@attr="value"]
```

Example (using [`findall()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall)):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """
<parent>
    <child attr="test">1</child>
    <child attr="something else">2</child>
    <child other_attr="other">3</child>
    <child>4</child>
    <child attr="test">5</child>
</parent>
"""

parent = ET.fromstring(data)
print [child.text for child in parent.findall('.//child[@attr]')]
print [child.text for child in parent.findall('.//child[@attr="test"]')]
```

Prints:

```
['1', '2', '5']
['1', '5']
```

Comment: Why assume that all of these nodes are going to be direct children of the root element?  What about if the *children and grandchildren*, or descendants at any level of nesting, have these attributes? `parent.findall('.//[@attr]')` throws an invalid descendant error in Python 2.7.

Comment: @alex wait, `//` or `.//` would look for node at any level of nesting. Or, I misunderstood your question..thanks.

Comment: @alex ah, if you mean to look for any node name, use `.//*[@attr]`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good sample/start script using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lxml import etree
fp = open("xml.xml")
tree = etree.parse(fp)
for el in tree.findall('//node[@attr="something"]'):
    print(el.text)
```